# Overriding an interpreter failure message in a FormFunction expression

Tags: gui-construction, interpreter

I am building a Form to capture several non-zero numbers as inputs. The basic code is:

```
Ratesform =
  FormFunction[{"DriftRates", ""} -> RepeatingElement[
        <|"Interpreter" ->  Interpreter["Number", 
        Function[x, x != 0]],  
        "Hint" -> "Non-zero values only", 
        "Label" :> "Drift rate " <> ToString[i]|>, {{i, 2}, {1, 10}}], 
        AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Enter the possible drift rates", 
        "SubmitLabel" -> "Submit"|>][];
```

This produces a form that only accepts non-zero values. But, if the user does enter a 0, it provides the Help "Enter a valid value." I want to override that to read "Enter a non-zero value".

[image: Help for 0 entry]

Given the value 0, the Interpreter returns a Failure Object with 
Message: "Enter a valid value.", 
Tag: ConditionFailure
Input: 0
Type: Number

[image: Interpreter's Failure]

So I figured adding a Failure option to the Interpreter would do the trick:

```
Ratesform =
  FormFunction[{"DriftRates", ""} -> RepeatingElement[
        <|"Interpreter" ->  Interpreter["Number", 
        Function[x, x != 0], 
        Failure["ConditionFailure", 
        <|"MessageTemplate"-> StringTemplate["Enter a non-zero number"]|>]],  
        "Hint" -> "Non-zero values only", 
        "Label" :> "Drift rate " <> ToString[i]|>, {{i, 2}, {1, 10}}], 
        AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Enter the possible drift rates", 
        "SubmitLabel" -> "Submit"|>][];
```

But that provides no help at all. How to override the default Failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure argument of the `Interpreter` call must be a function, so just add an `&` at the end of that argument. Like so.

```
Ratesform =
  FormFunction[
    {"DriftRates", ""} ->
      RepeatingElement[
        <|"Interpreter" ->
            Interpreter[
              "Number", # != 0 &,
              (* the following arg must be a function *)
              Failure[
                "ConditionFailure", 
                <|"MessageTemplate" -> 
                    StringTemplate["Enter a non-zero number"]|>] &],
          "Hint" -> "Non-zero values only", 
          "Label" :> "Drift rate " <> ToString[i]|>, {{i, 2}, {1, 10}}], 
    AppearanceRules ->
      <|"Title" -> "Enter the possible drift rates", 
        "SubmitLabel" -> "Submit"|>][]
```

[image: form]